# Calculating SpeedUp and efficiency in weak scaling

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc

As an exercise I got to use game of Life algorithm, I understood that the idea in implantation is to use weak scaling so more process means bigger problem size.
I am trying to find the speed up and efficiency but the normal speed up formula isn't good for this case. I do have the runtime for 1 process and 8 process what is the right calculation for the speed up and the efficiency

I tried to understand how to use Gustafson but for my case it doesn't works our because I need to calculate the speed up and efficiency with the runtime of 1 process and 8 process